# c# udp socket packet loss

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, udp

I have been testing with UDP and I am experiencing extreme packet loss, as much as 50%. These are a couple of the udp socket examples I have tested. I have tested others and still getting the same results.

Synchronous

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-udp-services

Async udp socket example

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginsend?view=net-6.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive?view=net-6.0

The pc that runs the udp listener also is running wire shark. Wire shark is reporting the same exact number of packets as the app running the udp listener.

The other pc that runs the sender is sending packets as fast as the thread runs there is no Thread.Sleep between sends. Wire shark on this pc is reporting the correct number of packets being sent by the sender.

I cannot figure out why so many packets are being dropped when sending them in fast succession. I cannot figure out if the pc sending the packets is really sending as many as it should be even though wire shark says it is. I don't know if the pc receiving them is not able to receive packets so rapidly. Also thinking the router could be the issue blocking a large number of packets for some reason. Also tried several TCP examples sending packets the same speed as the UDP and every packet is received by the listener in an instant even when sending tens of thousands.

Any ideas why udp listener is receiving so few packets?

Comment: You are probably sending faster than the interface bandwidth, so frames get dropped by the interface hardware. That is after Wireshark would see them. The hardware only has a tiny queue, and once it is filled, frames are dropped.

Comment: Is there a way to check the hardware ques size and limit?

Comment: Maybe, but it is only going to be a few frames (hardware queues are expensive). UDP is connectionless with no guarantees. TCP has congestion control and flow control, so it reacts very quickly to such congestion and slows to an acceptable sending rate, but UDP simply sends without caring whether or not the datagram is received.

Comment: I’ll write in a rate limiter when I have a chance to the udp sender to see if the packet rate receive rate increases as the limiter is adjusted.

Comment: Added a limiter to the udp sender pack loss went from 50-60% down to 8-9% which is still high but way better. Need to figure out how to get it down to 1% now.

Comment: You can take the bandwidth of the interface to calculate the proper rate. Remember to take into account the overhead of the data-link, network, transport, and any application-layer protocols that you are using. You should be able to calculate an ideal rate, that will get you down to less than 1% drop in you sender.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ron! Got the packet loss down below 1 pecent.

Turns out increasing the listeners buffer size helps a lot too. client.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 4096;